# Passing commands to subprocess in shell

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, apache-karaf

If a certain command (in my case ./karaf) runs a sub-process in a shell, that accepts its own commands, is there someway to execute the subsequently listed commands in a script as commands to the subprocess?
For example,

`sudo ./karaf`

opens a process in the shell that accepts its own commands. If I run this from a shell script, and then want the command

```
feature:install odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-u
```

to be run INSIDE the ./karaf program, how do I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect commands to karaf like:

```
./sudo karaf < echo 'feature:install'
```

But I wouldn't recommend you to do that. You see shell will pass the command imidiatelly to karaf which isn't ready to accept those commands (I assume it takes some time for karaf to initialize itself)

Instead you'd better execute command via karaf client.

```
./bin/client feature:install
```

Comment: This was just what I needed! Unfortunately I'm getting an error message when using sudo ./client feature:install <feature> 
197 [pool-2-thread-2] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at /0.0.0.0:8101 presented unverified key:
Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: To be honest I haven't work with karaf so far. I used  servicemix container with client. It seems like apache listens port 8010 for ssh connections. And afaik ssh generates public keys for auth. This article should clear things for you. http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/start-stop.html#Connect

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the answer. :)